# How to assign a variable the output of a shell command in Tupfile?

Tags: tup

I'd like to assign a variable in a Tupfile the output of the command `find . -name "*.cpp" -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
BOTAN_CFLAGS = `pkg-config botan-1.10 --cflags`
```

NOTE: the *back-tick* character "`"

However this only seems to work in the *command* section of the rules not the *dependencies*.

Comment: According to https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/tup/tup.1.en#var~2 this doesn't actually work, it just passes the string, backticks and all, to whatever uses it.

Comment: @AdamJRichardson Yes, but if you read further, the command will be passed to the shell when the variable is used later by a command. It is unclear what the OP's use case was, but I assume it was compatible with my answer as he gave me a tick :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the manual, the variable assignment does not cause the shell command to be executed. Instead, it is stored as regular string. Then when the variable is passed to a command, the shell expands it. It means that if you have K files to compile, the `shell expression` will be evaluated K times.